# Bootstrap 4 cards - float right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the card element to create a chat UI for my application.
This is the loop I'm using:

```
{% for message in messages %}
        <div class="card w-50">
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ message.content }}
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I was hoping to float messages to left and right, depending on the sender (so if the current user is the sender, the card would be on the right side).
However, I can't get the float to work.
Is there a helper class I could use to have some cards on the left, and some on the right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ml-auto`. This is a Bootstrap 4 util for `margin-left:auto;` that will push the card to the right...

https://www.codeply.com/go/FrJrmUxydZ

```
    <div class="ml-auto card w-50">
        <div class="card-body">
            {{ message.content }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

There is also `float-right` but this will cause cards to overlap each other.