# Alignment of card group Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I having a hard time with a simple problem: aligning a card group using Bootstrap. Cant get it to center or at least flush right so that it wont cover my left sidebar.

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-5 g-8">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="img/heart.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
       <img src="img/heart.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="img/heart.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
       <img src="img/heart.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Blessings,
Meka

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 cards - float right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992436/bootstrap-4-cards-float-right)

Comment: Thank ya so very much!!!                                                                                                                Actually I used this and it did the trick:  <div class="row justify-content-center">